# How to make a REST based web app stable and resilient (Kubernetes/Docker)

Tags: scala, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I have an app that is part of a microservices cluster, and I want to make sure my service is stable and resilient.

Its highly important that it will be available all the time.

The app is written in scala

Web framework is play

running the app on a docker and kubernetes is managing the containers in the cluster.

not using queues or anything, request comes, and get response (calculations returns Futures of course)

im new to the dev ops area and I want to make sure my service is resilient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your application it’s hard to determine all the requirements.
Here are the few I can think of.

- Run more the on pods. To handle pod failure scenario
- Make sure podsspreads across all the kubernetes nodes.  To handle the node failure.
- Setup the service as round robin.  Traffic will be shared across all
  the pods.
- Monitor the transaction latency.